# How to write KeyBindings

Tags: user-interface, keyboard, game-physics, keylistener

I am developing a Java 2D Game, in which I have used a KeyListener, but as you probably can guess, it has focusing issues, mainly when the Player is running and you keep the same key pressed for long, for example pressing "W" to run forward, but after some seconds of keep pressing W, the KeyListener dies and no key works, I want to use KeyBindings, as most people suggest it for game development, but I cannot find any usefull tutorials, most of them use some form of Buttons, and other useless features for my game, so how can i avoid the KeyListener from losing focus, or how can I write a simple KeyBinding code, that only moves the player, and other simple stuff used in a game.

This is the kind of Key Binding that I want, I KNOW IT DOES NOT WORK, it is an example:

```
component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(VK_W),
                        "move forward")
component.getActionMap().put("released",
                         releasedAction);
if(releasedAction == true){
Player.playerSpeedY = 7;
} else{
Player.playerSpeedY = 0;
}
```

FWI: this is the current KeyListener code:

```
if(HUD.PlayerHealth > 0){
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {Player.playerSpeedY = -5; keyDown[0]= true;}
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {Player.playerSpeedY = 5; keyDown [1]= true;}
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {Player.playerSpeedX = -5; keyDown [2]= true;}
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {Player.playerSpeedX = 5; keyDown [3]= true;}
    }
```

I keep looking for Actions and Input maps tutorials, or KeyBinding ones, and I just don't find anything useful, another dough, the component in action and input map, what is it for?, should my entire code be based on that, and is there any way to only make the action map move the player, and only that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
  this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "right");
  this.getActionMap().put("right", new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      //Do Something Here
     Player.playerSpeedX = 5;

    }
  });
```

[How to use KeyBindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)